# Detecting web page updates with python

Tags: python, html, parsing, text, web

What would be the simplest way to check a web page for changes? I want to scan a web page every so often, and compare it to an older scan. One problem is I also need the scan to ignore certain changes, such as the time of day, etc. I only want to check for relevant updates.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). Simplest way is to download the page (using [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)) and compare with old version.

Answer (score 4):

I won't write code, but I'll give you the process I'd go through for solving this problem:

1. Retrieve the source of the page
2. Replace out all of the parts
   of the page that we don't care to monitor
3. Calculate an md5 or
   sha1 hash of the source after replacements are made
4. Compare the
   hash with the stored hash, see if it's different, and do whatever
   you need to do if the page has been updated
5. Store the new hash

Comment: How would I replace a part that constantly changes though? Such as the time of day being displayed. I was first trying to use urllib2, but weird bugs kept popping up. I was trying to focus on certain areas of the page source using a.read()[xxx:yyy], which seemed to work, but then for some reason the saved value would become empty, and urllib2.urlopen was returning info that seemed entirely wrong (couldn't even find it on the web page). So now I'm just confused.

Comment: look into using [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). They're quite handy.