# How to check for a image update on a website?

Tags: image, logging, web

How can I check if an image file is changed on a website, from another website and then store it and the old version?

I'm using this to log the images on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a quick sketch of the simplest approach. If you want more detail on some part, just ask in the comments.

## Sketch of solution

1. Download the image, compute a hash for it and store the image in file system and image ID + hash + file system path (and possibly other info such as time of request) in database.
2. When checking for update, get last available info for the same ID from the database and if hashes are not the same, the image was not updated. If you use cryptographic hash like MD5 or SHA1 and the hash changed, it is almost sure that the image changed too.
3. Setup a cronjob to run the script periodically.

To download the image, you could use [`$img = file_get_contents($url);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). MD5 can be computed via [`$hash = md5($img);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php), SHA1 via [`$hash = sha1($img);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php). For storing use [`file_put_contents($path, $img);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

## Optimization

There are several ways to optimize the job.

To cut on memory consumption, download the file directly to file system using `file_put_contents($path, $url);` and only after that compute the hash using [`$hash = md5_file($path);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) or [`$sha1_file($path);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php). This is better for larger images. The bad thing is that you have to read the data from file system again to compute the hash, so I think it would be slower.

*Side note: Never optimize anything before you know that it really makes the code better. Always measure before, after and compare.*

Another optimization could be done for saving on data transfers from remote server if the server sends reliable headers for caching. ETag is the best one because it should be based on the contents of the file. If it does not change, file should be the same. If you want just to check the headers, use [`$headers = get_headers($url, 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php). To fetch really just the headers, you should issue just HTTP request via HEAD method instead of GET. Check `get_headers()` manual for more info. To check the headers while getting response body, use `file_get_contents()` along with [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) special variable.

Issuing requests indicating that you cached the image on last visit (via `If-Modified-Since` et al.) could serve the same purpose.

## Etiquette and legal aspects

I told you how. Now I’ll tell you when (not).

Do not abuse the remote server. Remember that its owner has expenses to keep it up and running and definitely does not want to let it be occupied by your scripts for more than a negligible amount of time, transferring not much data. Adapt your polling period to type of target server and size of image. Adapting it to estimated frequency of change is not a bad idea too.

Be sure to have consent of image rights holder when storing its copy. Licensing can be a messy thing. Be careful, otherwise you can get into trouble.

If you plan to somehow crawl for the images, [robots.txt](/questions/tagged/robots.txt) standard might be of your interest. This file could tell you that you are not welcome and you should respect it.

## Related questions

Some are related more, some less. People want to watch mainly HTML pages. That has other specifics, which is also why I did not flag this question as duplicate of one of these.

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/11336431/2157640
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/11182825/2157640
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/13398512/2157640
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/15207145/2157640
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/1494488/2157640

Comment: image ID + hash + file system path as the name of the image?
Do I just simply replace the $url as the url?
I really don't have much experience on php, I haven't been running websites that much.

Comment: @tonkku107 Do you really need to use PHP? Using shell it would be more straightforward I believe. By “file system path” I meant path to the image, including its name. You could store the whole image to the database, but databases were not built to store large binary blobs so it kills their performance, AFAIK. Also transferring large amounts data between application and database is not desirable as database often runs on a separate host.

Comment: @tonkku107 The image name could be e.g. its contents hash, if you know it when creating it. Otherwise you could pick a temporary name and later rename it. Maybe creating a directory for each watched URL is not a bad idea if you expect lots of versions for some of the URLs.

Comment: No I don't need to use php, but it's on a webserver, that I can't get hands on the shell. The amount of data isn't big... The images are just about 2KB.

Comment: @tonkku107 Are you experienced in programming generally? PHP is trivial to learn. Do you know how HTTP works and can you use database? I provided you with all you need to write you image update watching program. What else do you need to mark my answer accepted?

Comment: I have exprience on general programming and HTML. I can use a Database. Is it just those lines, or do I need more to make it functional?

Comment: @tonkku107 I am afraid you want me to write the code for you. I will not do it. What lines do you mean? The sample use of the functions I recommend for implementation? Writing them one after another in a PHP script surely does not produce the script you want. Knowing basic programming (what a variable is, how assignment a control structures work, …), names of functions you need to use and the overall algorithm… What else would you possibly need? If there is anything, I’ll gladly help, but I don’t see it now.

Comment: I don't know PHP really, I know echo, and how to start and stop a php script. I just know HTML, and a little js and css.

Comment: @tonkku107 Wait, you said that you have experience in programming. You know what a for-loop is, how if statement works, what variables and functions are… With this knowledge and PHP short manual consultations you must be able to write basic code in PHP. And the thing you want really is basic code in PHP. Just determining which functions to use is not that trivial, so I gave you links to their manual pages. Another possible answer to this could be: If you don’t know PHP, don’t try to write PHP code. Learn it first!

Comment: @tonkku107 From the questions I link to in my answer I got these links: http://www.changedetect.com/ http://www.changedetection.com/ Maybe one of these services could do what you need. But if you need to find a tool, library, etc., StackExchange is probably not a good place to go. See [help/on-topic] for more information on what is on topic and what not.